# How to describe One To One relationships from Django ORM in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following models in Django:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    # some fields
    image = models.ForeignKey("media.Image",blank=True, null=True)

# and in another django module
class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
```

In Postgres it looks like:

```
=> \d newsfeed_news

   Column    |           Type           |                         Modifiers                          
-------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                  | not null default nextval('newsfeed_news_id_seq'::regclass)
 
...

 image_id    | integer                  |
```

This means that the field "Image" in the table - is just integer field, containing ID of image.

I tried to build these relations in SQLAlchemy:

```
class Image(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'media_image'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column('url',String)

class newsTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'media_news'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # some fields
    image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Image.id'))
    image = relationship("Image", uselist=False)
```

But I got the following error:

> Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'newsfeed_news' and
> 'media_image'. Could not determine join condition between parent/child
> tables on relationship newsTable.image - there are no foreign keys
> linking these tables.
>
> Ensure that referencing columns are associated
> with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin'
> expression.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation [`ForeignKey`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey) accepts `column` parameter, which is defined as:

> A single target column for the key relationship. A `Column` object or a column name as a string: `tablename.columnkey` or `schema.tablename.columnkey`.

You try to specify column name as a string, but there is no table named `Image`. You can either reference `Column` object directly from `Image` model:

```
image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Image.id))
```

Or provide a correct table name:

```
image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('media_image.id'))
```